# Client Design in Java (Multiplayer Game)

Tags: java

Working on a browser game with a Java server backend and I'm wondering.. what's the best web "client" framework, or whatever, to use to design the client itself included on the page they'd visit to play? Any guides out there I can find? Completely new to this and wondering what is the best thing to design for it. Going to hope to work with some minimal 3D objects.

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by client? where you will render your graphics?

Comment: You might want to consider asking/migrating the question to http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: "browser game", without further detail, it's impossible to know what your requirements are. If it truly is a browser game, HTML/CSS/JavaScript would be your best bet, or HTML5 if you're wanting to build something cutting edge.